# VBA simple test if an integer is a repeating number?

Tags: vba

I have an integer I'd like to test to see if it is a repeating number, ie
999
9999
99999

the input value range for what the integer is being used for is any three to five digit number, and sometimes that number may be all 9's. Outside of just using multiple OR statements, I'm wondering if there is a more "elegant" way to test this?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1,1,1)=MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)))=LEN(A1)`

Comment: standing your "specs", I'd use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,9,"")=""`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this `=(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,1,1),""))=0)`

Comment: Shorter than mine and not an array type.  I like.

Comment: there's also the `string(mid(a1,1,1),len(a1))=a1` route also

Comment: I think you want REPT not STRING, but yeah.

Comment: Apologies, that was more of the pseudo VBA approach in my comment.  But formula wise, perfect, could be a million and 1 comments by tomorrow :)

Comment: vba the criteria are switched, the number comes first then the character.

Comment: hence pseudo ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a short little example to help you get started. This vba code checks to see if it is one of your repeating numbers (999,9999,99999) and makes a message box if it is or not one of your repeating numbers.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyVal As Long
    MyVal = Range("A1").Value

    If MyVal = 999 Or MyVal = 9999 Or MyVal = 99999 Then
        MsgBox "Integer is a repeating number."
    Else
        MsgBox "Integer is not a repeating number."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: OP: ***Outside of just using multiple OR statements**, I'm wondering if there is a more "elegant" way to test this*